# Converting a struct of floats to an array without having to iterate

Tags: go

I'm writing a geometry library in Go and therefore use a Point struct:

```
type Point struct {
    X, Y, Z float32
}
```

I pass an array of points to a function so it can render them but the function uses an array of n Points as

```
type Point [3]float32
```

I want to know if it's possible to translate the array of Point in O(1) without having to iterate over all the points.

Comment: Use argument [3]float32{p.X, p.Y, p.Z}.  If the function argument is [3]float32, then it's impossible to avoid copying the three floats.

Comment: Even _with_ iteration it would be O(1). At least for the common definition of O.

Comment: @Volker no you'll have to iterate over n points , it depends on the number of points , therefore it's in o(n) . i'm still a college student . i see you have a lot of experience . repect !

Comment: @Tawfik Maybe we are talking about different things. If you have to convert n `Point`s then each and every (classical) algorithm will be O(n) and asking to do it in O(1) is asking for magic and thus nonsensical. Note that just by you utilizing some magical sugar (which Go doesn't provide) which _hides_ the O(n) making it look like a single statement doesn't magically _make_ it  O(1). Converting a single `Point` is O(1) no matter how many coordinates it has (as long as the number of coordinates is fixed).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Point struct {
    X, Y, Z float32
}

func (p *Point) toArray() [3]float32{
  return [3]float32{p.X, p.Y, p.Z}
}

func main() {
    point := Point{1, 2, 3}
    fmt.Println(point.toArray())
}
```

Output:

```
[1 2 3]
```

[Live demo](https://play.golang.org/p/4Jb6H2zcXoO)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in Go you can convert a slice of `Point` to a slice of `[3]float32` in O(1). However, to do so requires the use of [unsafe](https://pkg.go.dev/unsafe). Package unsafe comes with the following warning:

> Packages that import unsafe may be non-portable and are not protected by the Go 1 compatibility guidelines.

Below is a minimal Go program that demonstrates the technique:

```
// Convert a slice of (struct of float32) to a slice of (array of float32) in
// O(1).
//
// The (struct of float32) and (array of float32) types shall have the same
// number of float32s.
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "golang.org/x/exp/slices"

    "github.com/bcmills/unsafeslice"
)

type Point struct {
    X, Y, Z float32
}

func main() {
    src := []Point{{X: 1, Y: 2, Z: 3}, {X: 4, Y: 5, Z: 6}}
    var dst [][3]float32
    unsafeslice.ConvertAt(&dst, src)
    // src and dst now point to the same memory region but at a different type.

    fmt.Printf("  src: %v\n", src)
    fmt.Printf("  dst: %v\n", dst)
    fmt.Printf("equal: %v\n", slices.Equal(
        dst,
        [][3]float32{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}},
    ))
}
```

Running this program will produce the following output:

```
  src: [{1 2 3} {4 5 6}]
  dst: [[1 2 3] [4 5 6]]
equal: true
```